# Application error: Client Side Exception when clicking the Link on the Not Found Page for unathenticated users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, supabase

I encountered a problem where if I put a Link on the not found page, clicking the link will show this on the screen: Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).  This error only shows up for those unauthenticated users. No error shows for those who are authenticated. Any idea what is wrong with the application?

Github repo: https://github.com/Jennelle186/NextJS-Supabase

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My `middleware.ts`:

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const res = NextResponse.next()
  const supabase = createMiddlewareClient({ req, res })

  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser()


  // if user is not signed in and the current path is not /login redirect the user to /
  if (!user && req.nextUrl.pathname !== '/login') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.url))
  }

  return res
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/water_station:path', '/waterTypes:path',],
```

The login `route.ts`:

```
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url)
  const formData = await request.formData()
  const email = String(formData.get('email'))
  const password = String(formData.get('password'))
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies: () => cookieStore })

  await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
    email,
    password,
  })

  return NextResponse.redirect(requestUrl.origin, {
    status: 301,
  })
}
```

**Layout.tsx**

```
import { NavBar } from '@/components';
import './globals.css';
import {Inter} from 'next/font/google';

import AuthProvider from "@/components/Auth/Authprovider";
import { createServerComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs"
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

//tried adding this
export const revalidate = 0;
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Water Refilling Station',
  description: 'Generated by Next.js',
}

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  const supabase = createServerComponentClient({cookies});

  const {
    data: { session },
  } = await supabase.auth.getSession();

  const accessToken = session?.access_token || null;
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} antialiased`}>
      <NavBar session={session}/>
      <AuthProvider accessToken={accessToken}>{children}</AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**Page.tsx**

```
import { createServerActionClient, createServerComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs"
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import ViewAllWaterStation from "@/app/water_station/ViewAllWaterStation";
import Link from "next/link";

export default async function Home() {
  const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies });

  const {data: {session }} = await supabase.auth.getSession();

  // if(!session){
  //   redirect('/login')
  // }
  return (
    <main className="overflow-hidden">
      {/* if logged in, this is what the user will be able to view */}
      {/* If logged in, water stations account do not need to see all of the list of the water stations */}
      {session ? (<> <h1 className="text-center underline"></h1> </>) 

        : 
      (<>
      {/* Shows all of the water stations for those unauthenticated users */}
      <Link href="/login">Login Here</Link>
      <ViewAllWaterStation/> 
      </>)}    
      </main>
  )
}
```

**Errors:**

```
app-index.js:31 Warning: Extra attributes from the server: data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded,data-gr-ext-installed
    at body
    at html
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:72:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:80:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:32:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:297:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:158:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:100:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:130:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:441:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:127:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:143:11)
```

Then I found this as well:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
app-index.js:31 Warning: Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`Router`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Router`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:158:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:100:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:130:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:441:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:127:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:143:11)
window.console.error @ app-index.js:31
```

**Lastly:**

```
Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
    at updateWorkInProgressHook (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11246:15)
    at updateCallback (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12328:14)
    at Object.useCallback (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13271:14)
    at useCallback (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react.development.js:1767:21)
    at useReducerWithReduxDevtoolsImpl (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/use-reducer-with-devtools.js:103:41)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:175:169)
    at renderWithHooks (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10930:18)
    at updateFunctionComponent (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16072:20)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18268:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20367:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20416:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20491:29)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26669:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25493:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25479:5)
    at renderRootConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25435:9)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:38)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:261:34)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:230:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:534:21
    

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln0bd.png
```

Comment: As the screenshot says, the actual error is *above* the log you posted. You need to post what the actual error is. The error occurs on the front end also, so the front end code is more relevant.

Comment: @adsy Added the errors already

Comment: The main issue here is the last one. It looks like you have a React hook which is used inside an if condition, which is not allowed as per the rules of hooks. This originates from the "app-router" file. Can you post the source of that?

Comment: @adsy I am using the App Router` of NextJS so I am unsure where the error originated from but I also posted my  `layout.tsx` and `page.tsx`. Here is the Github repo: https://github.com/Jennelle186/NextJS-Supabase